# per day plus one to a certain number

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Js. I have a table that shows me 9 persons. I have added the number of days they are in the group. I am trying to create a function that counts per day +1 to this number. Has somebody an Idea how i can do that?

This is my Code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></th>
                <th>Spieler</th>
                <th>Rang</th> 
                <th>Tage</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>HELLFIRE944</td>
                <td>Komandant</td> 
                <td>212</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Backfischjoghurt</td>
                <td>Ausführender Offizier</td> 
                <td>217</td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>retoaba</td>
                    <td>Personaloffizier</td> 
                    <td>210</td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input class="checkbox"  type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>chrisi_39</td>
                    <td>Rekrutierungsoffizier</td> 
                    <td>210</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>salpo</td>
                    <td>Unteroffizier</td> 
                    <td>212</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Kaeltischerkriger</td>
                    <td>Unteroffizier</td> 
                    <td>213</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>DnerYoo_sniper</td>
                    <td>Rekrut</td> 
                    <td>39</td>
               </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>panzerzockerundnoah</td>
                    <td>Rekrut</td> 
                    <td>146</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>PanzaSintKuhlMinecraftLP</td>
                    <td>Rekrut</td> 
                    <td>116</td>
               </tr>
            </table> 
                <footer class=footer>
                    <div class=footer>
                        <p class= footer-p>created by @Reto Keller</p>
                    </div>
                </footer>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get Tage +1 for every table row ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i mean

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, it returns you the whole array of tableData values of Tage.
[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XIL2rl?p=info)

```
function getAllTableDataValues() {

  var row = $('table tr'); //get all table rows
  var rowData = row.find('td:nth-child(4n)'); // get all the table data with Tage
  var numberArray = [];
  rowData.each(function() {
    var value = $(this).html(); //get the value of td in string format array
    value = Number(value);
    value = value +1;
    numberArray.push(value);
    });

  return numberArray;

}

getAllTableDataValues();
```